# ¿Cómo hacer para que el return se ejecute después de completarse la petición ajax?

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

La respuesta es true si el usuario existe en la db, pero no sé cómo cambiar el valor del final de manera asíncrona.

```
$("#login_form").submit(function(){
    let final = false;
    let object = {
        data: {
            'user': $("#user_login").val(),
            'pass': $("#pass_login").val(),
            'type': true,
        },
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'POST'
    }
    ajax(object).then(function resolve(response){
        if(!response){
            errorDiv("#user_login", "#C62828");
            errorDiv("#pass_login", "#C62828");
        }else{
            final = true;
        }
    }, function reject(){
        console.log("Error");
    });
    return final;
});

function ajax (object){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        $.ajax(object).done(resolve).fail(reject);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cuanto ejecutas un ajax **se crea un hilo nuevo el cual se ejecuta de forma independiente al código que lo llamó**.

En el ejemplo que indicas, aunque no está muy claro pareces querer devolver algo según lo que devuelva el ajax.

En dicho caso lo mejor sería que el ajax modificase algo del DOM, un campo input hidden o similar, en dicho caso tendrías que tener un setTimeout que estuviera comprobando el cambio de ese input.

Otra opción es que sea ajax el que haga el window.location para cambiar la página en caso que sea un login correcto.

Sin más código por tu parte es dificil ayudarte poniéndote código.

Comment: Sí, utilicé una solución parecida, gracias por comentar

Comment: Si la respuesta era true, cargaba la pagina de login y mandaba las variables de user y pass de forma global con session_start() por php.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacerlo sí. Y tranquilo este desconocimiento de que el Ajax se ejecuta en otro hilo es muy común. Me alegra que lo hayas solucionado. La próxima vez pon algo de código ;-)